# How to merge multiple PDF input streams to produce an output stream without storing them in memory?

Tags: java, pdf, stream, pipe

Recently, I received a lot of out of memory errors due to merging a number of PDF files. I was wondering if it would be possible to do something like this:

```
public OutputStream mergePdf(List<InputStream> inputStreams) {
    SomePDFLib pdfLib = new SomePDFLib();
    inputStreams.forEach(stream -> pdfLib.addStream(stream));
    return pdfLib.getMergedStream();
}
```

Basically, I would like to pipe all the input streams into an output stream containing a merged PDF without having to keep the input streams in memory.

I went through the documentation of PDFBox and IText but couldn't find anything in either of them. Also, searched through StackOverflow but most of the questions talk about either merging multiple PDF files which are present on the disk or are in a stream which is loaded to the memory.

Any of you know of any ways this could be accomplished? A library that provides this functionality out of the box would be amazing since I don't know much about the internals of the PDF file type.

Comment: Define "merging". If you want to stream files one after another, you can do that without any libraries, by concatenating `InputStream`s into `SequenceInputStream`.

Comment: The internal config of the PDF file format means that simple concatenating of streams is not possible. As a metaphor. think of it as each PDF being a book with a table of contents and page numbers - you want to merge the books so the table of contents and page numbers have to be managed properly to be of any use after the merge. That's what PDF processing libraries & components do for you, but it is much more complicated than that.

Comment: *"PDFBox and IText"* - PDFBox requires the whole result pdf to be built in memory. IText may allow for a smaller memory footprint, at least as long as no form fields are  concerned.